# PHP/Cronjob Mail Function

Tags: php, email, cron

I have a website on the web, and I want to use CronJob, to send newsletters every Monday.
Now, I'm using PHP to do this, and I'm stuck.
I have a mail() function, that sends mail, to every address stated in a file.

Here is my CronJob file. I changed the date to everyday, just for debugging.

```
0 9 * * *   php -f /home/a4770799/public_html/mail/newsletter.php
```

Here is my PHP file. This is the whole file.

```
<?php
  $subject = "Weekly Newsletter";
  $msg = "This is a weekly newsletter debugging test.";
  $headers = "From: noreply@test.com" . "\r\n" .
             "Reply-To: example@test.com" . "\r\n";
  $linesofmail = file("mail_address_list.txt");
  foreach ($linesofmail as $line_num => $line) {
    mail ($line, $subject, $msg, $headers);
  }
?>
```

What might be the problem here? I would love it, if someone would explain the problem to me, instead of just giving me a piece of code.

Comment: If you're running the script from a public directory - does it work?

Comment: I've tried one before. That one did work. If the PHP function, is perfectly correct, as you say, it might be the problem with being in a public directory.

Comment: Just use these to send email ? The email will probably fall into Junk box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out the error log. It can be problem reading the mail_address_list.txt or php mail error.

[Check this out](http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/ian_gilfillan20060412.php3) to prevent mails moving to junk.

Comment: That link is very useful! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: the link does not help much on junk mail. Try these keywords: DKIM, SPF, SpamAssassin, Razor, Pyzor